# jquery colorbox isn't working with mootools v1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I wanna use colorbox for 'join us menu' but it isn't working.

and I also tried fancybox, and got a same result..

actually colorbox performed well until I add mootools v1.1 to my jsp code.

I dont know what is mootools v1.1. I just copy some source that from

some awesome website for

using scroll view effect(I dont know exactly what this effect's name) on my page

scroll view effect is working well. you can see that when you clicked 'append1,2,3'

sorry for my poor english skill.

here is my code

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Spring Builder : append your heart </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.v1.1.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('.joinus').colorbox({

    });

});

</script>


<style type="text/css">

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}

#main_header{

    width:1280px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height:60px;
    background: #59DA50;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}
#main_bar{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #EAEAEA;

}
#main_bar>ul.main_bar_left{
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#main_bar>ul.main_bar_right{
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
#main_bar>ul.main_bar_left>li{
    float:left;

}
#main_bar>ul.main_bar_right>li{
    float:left;

}
#main_bar a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
}
#main_bar a:HOVER{

    background: #CEF279;
}

#main_bar input{

    margin:5px;
    width: 80px;

}

#main_footer{
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    background: #353535;
    color: #FFFFFF;

    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}


#main_content {
margin:0px;
overflow:hidden; 
/*height:387px; 
width:99,9%;*/
border:none;
position:relative;
}

#main_content_bg {
width:5000px;
height:600px;
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/5000x600);
background-position:top left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#E6E6E4;
position:relative;
}

.section_content {
width:990px;
height:380px;
position:absolute;
}

#section1 {
left:0px; 
top:0px;
}

#section2 {
left:1570px; 
top:0px;
}

#section3 {
left:2880px; 
top:0px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<header id="main_header">
    <h1>Spring Builder</h1>
</header>

<nav id="main_bar">
    <ul class="main_bar_left">
        <li><a id="append1" href="#">append1</a></li>
        <li><a id="append2" href="#">append2</a></li>
        <li><a id="append3" href="#">append3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="main_bar_right">
        <li><input type="text" value="id" id="id" name="id"/></li>
        <li><input type="password" id="pw" name="pw"/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="SbMember.jsp" class="joinus">Join us</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>

<div id="main_content">
    <div id="main_content_bg">
        <div id="section1" class="section_content">
        <h1>section1</h1></div>
        <div id="section2" class="section_content">
        <h1>section2</h1></div>
        <div id="section3" class="section_content">
        <h1>section3</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>  
<footer id="main_footer">

</footer>
<script src="scrollstyle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific about what you mean by "it isn't working".

Comment: It means when I click 'join us', just go to anotherpage. I want activate lightbox effect and new page show in lightbox. but isnt working and just go to anotherpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably happen a conflict between Mootools and jQuery because both libraries are using `$` sign, try to convert `$` to jQuery for your jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.joinus').colorbox({

    });
});
```

or wrap your code inside:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.joinus').colorbox({

    });
});
```

Comment: that won't work with mootools 1.11. it does not play nice with $ and will overwrite it. load mootools first then jquery in noConflict mode or better yet, use mootools 1.4.5 in compat mode.

Comment: I already try to change mootools 1.1 to 1.45. But when I put 1.45 on myPage, colorbox is working very well but scroll view isnt working..